# SSAS: Get a distinct Count based on two different elements

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube

I need to create a distinct count of people who fall into two different dimensions.

One is called [Student Research Degree].[Is Research Degree Current].&[Yes]
The other is called [Student Research Degree].[Is Research Degree Complete].&[Yes]

If one or the other are Yes, or both, then I need to count the record.
If both are no, I can exclude it.  I have a row counter measure called [Measures].[Student ID Distinct Count Hidden] already in place.

If I use just one element with the measure, I get the right answer, but if I try to cross join the other elements, I get a result of NULL.

eg

```
AGGREGATE(CROSSJOIN(
    [Student Research Degree].[Is Research Degree Current].&[Yes] 
        ,[Student Research Degree].[Is Research Degree Complete].&[Yes]
), [Measures].[Student ID Distinct Count Hidden])
```

I am aware that I can just land an extra value in the ETL, and have SQL do the work, and in the end this might be the solution.  Is there a way of doing an OR statement on this sort of thing?

Comment: Distinct count is a very problematic measure. I would strongly suggest doing it via the SQL since the measure that you've got in place won't help you. Look here: https://blog.tallan.com/2017/02/09/analysis-services-tabular-many-to-many-relationships-bridge-tables-and-blank-members/

Comment: Does this code work for you ?
`AGGREGATE(
    {[Student Research Degree].[Is Research Degree Current].&[Yes] 
        ,[Student Research Degree].[Is Research Degree Complete].&[Yes]}
, [Measures].[Student ID Distinct Count Hidden])`

Answer (score 0):

No, the TUPLE of &[YES], &[YES] doesn't create an OR situation, where I want [NO]s when the other is yes.

I started looking at a subtractive approach where I started with the ALL set, and removed the distinct count of invalid combinations in a tuple and subtracted that from the grand total.  This approach did work, but ONLY because the data allowed for it.  If a person could have been in multiple combinations, this wouldn't have worked.

I'm currently testing that approach with the rest of the cube.  By all appearances this works perfectly, but I will go with ETL if any bugs or mismatches can be proven.